# Cordova + Apple Watch - how to set up

Tags: cordova, apple-watch

I'm quite new in developing apps for apple. So I have an exisiting app written in JavaScript and Angular and so on. This one I added to a Phonegap project and build an iOS app via CLI. Which works when I open it on iPhone.
So now I want to extend its functions and add the functionality to communicate with an Apple Watch. So my way was to install the apple-watch plugin via CLI, to open the iOS project of this app in Xcode and then add the Watchkit as target. In result of that I get some errors when I try to build it. Before adding everything's fine.

My question now is if this was the right setup or do I have to change some config files to make it work in general?

For now it's not about the code, just the general way how to do it. Didn't find the proper information until now, and I searched (maybe I'm not a good searcher, but I did).

**Update:**

*For me the solution of the error "Bridging-Header" file not found (#import ) was to delete that line or comment it out. Then the build is successful*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet, have to test it but this one seems to be a legit way:

https://github.com/ogoguel/cordova-apple-watch-conduit

Will try and thank myself if it works

Comment: Anyone using this plugin successfully? It hasn't been updated in 4 years.